# Trigger jenkins pipeline on hook trigger when changes are pushed to specific branch

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project on GitHub with branch master, develop and Develop_Sprint1. I have a pipeline to checkout a code, build and test.

I need to trigger this job with webhook trigger when changes are made to specific branch like develop.

Can you please help me in setting this.

Comment: Could you provide your pipeline? Is it declarative or scripted?
Also, check [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003945572-Pipeline-Build-with-git-step-on-a-specific-branch-is-triggered-by-a-different-branch) article.

Comment: Why not use multi-branch pipeline? It would do this for you.